# Interpret strings as packed binary data, Python vs Java

Tags: java, python, binary, struct, byte

I'm struggling a bit with binary in Java and Python to translate a program

In python when I execute the following commands, I've got

```
>>> print ord(pack('>H', 32809)[0])
128

>>> print ord(pack('>H', 32809)[1])
41
```

In Java, I expect to have the same result when I execute the following command, but it's not there:

```
bsh % print ((byte)((32809 & 0xFF00) >> 8)); 
-128

bsh % print ((byte)(32809 & 0x00FF)); 
41
```

Can somebody explain me why 128 is negative in Java?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signed byte has a range of -128..127, so (127+1) == -128

Comment: does it means (byte)128 = -128 ?

Comment: Yes. Incrementing from 127 "wraps around" - the bit pattern for 127 is 0x7F; adding one gives 0x80; interpreted as a signed byte, this is -128. There are not enough bits in a signed byte to properly represent +128.

Answer (score 2):

Byte in java is a signed data type - and yeah I never understood why they did that either. You'll need to use a short (well since all bit ops are used on ints anyhow, just use a int really) and ignore the higher 8bit (otherwise sign extension would be a problem)

```
 System.out.println(((short) ((32809 & 0xFF00) >> 8)) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Or just `System.out.println((32809 >> 8) & 0xFF);`

Answer (score 0):

You won't have unsigned types in Java. You could consider casting it to a short or an int instead.

Comment: BTW `char` is an unsigned type. ;)

Comment: That's true, it is. But as far as numbers are concerned, you won't have unsigned types. Yes, I know it is valid to say `char c = 100;` but seeing how java.lang.Character doesn't extend Number, I don't consider it to be a number.